# How do i get IPhone IMEI?

Tags: c#, iphone, imei

How do i get IPhone IMEI?

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *identifier = myDevice.uniqueIdentifier;
```

This is the code i tried but isn't working.

Comment: I've removed the Visual Studio tag because this question is about code, and not about using the Visual Studio application.

Comment: That code appears to be Objective-C (or perhaps Swift? I'm not very familiar), not C#. Can you provide some more information about what you're doing? Are you using Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 7 Apple does not allow you to identify a device using IMEI any more.

You may have to use UDID instead.

Comment: Then how do i get the UDID?